# Why aren't Liferay objects rendering in my Velocity template?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-velocity

A simple example:

```
/* Get user roles */
#set($userId=$request.attributes.get('USER_ID'))
#set($roleLocalService=$serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.RoleLocalService"))
$roleLocalService.getUserRoles($userId)
```

What renders on the page is just the text with no data.

$roleLocalService.getUserRoles($userId)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

1. Be sure you're allowed to use `serviceLocator`. The [default value](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-impl/src/portal.properties#L8455) in `portal.properties` is `velocity.engine.restricted.variables=serviceLocator` which means `serviceLocator` is not available to templates. Set it to "blank" (or at least do not include `serviceLocator`). For example, set it to

`velocity.engine.restricted.variables=`

in a `portal-ext.properties` file inside the Liferay Home directory.

2. `$request.attributes.get` is going to give you the String value of the userId. So you need to convert this to a Long using something like:

`$roleLocalService.getUserRoles($getterUtil.getLong($userId))`